# Can not access Nodejs app which deployed on container of Bluemix

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I create an image from `cf ic` command line expose **4000** then install nodejs,npm via **apt-get** and deploy a nodejs app on the image listen on port **4000**.

And then I create a container with this image ,assign a **public_ip** to this container and run it.

But I found that I can not access the nodejs app with port [ http://**public_ip****4000** ].

When I login into container with command line `cf ic exec -it container_id bash`,I found that the nodejs app is running and I can access nodejs app by `curl -GET http://localhost:4000/`

Error Message is `:net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Q: How can I access my nodejs app outside container?

Comment: Could you please provide us the output of the command 'cf ic ps'? There you should see the port binding between the container and the host

Comment: Yes,I can see the port binding. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000->4000/tcp

Answer (score 0):

Port 4000 is not exposed to the IBM Containers firewall.

There is a limited set of ports exposed, so I suggest you try a different port like 3000 or 5000. The complete list is not published for security reasons.

Alternatively you can create a Container Group with a single container. In that case you can define a route (domain) for your container that will automatically route all requests internally to your container port (like 4000).

You can find more details about creating container groups in Bluemix documentation:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_group_ov